# Can I make a unique_ptr not to take the ownership of its pointed object?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a vector of unique pointers. Among them, I want one doesn't take the ownership of its pointed object. How to do it?

```
vector<unique_ptr<int>> v;
v.push_back(make_unique<int>(10));

unique_ptr<int> p(new int(20)); // add it to v but keep p take the ownership.
```

The question comes from the following case. I have a data with tree structure which is represented by a GUI tree widget. The parent node takes ownership of its children by using `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`. But there is an exception. I have a common singleton data, and want to append it to the tree also for friendly user interface. There is conflicts because sigleton also takes the ownership. Using share_ptr works, but sacrifice some performance.

Thanks for all your guys's answers, comments and suggestion. It may be a design flaw. Maybe I need a new class for the special parent node with `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` (for others) and `shared_ptr` or even a raw pointer (for the singleton) to deal with the exception.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the motive? Use raw pointer?

Comment: You can't - the name is **unique** pointer for a reason.

Comment: Why not use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`?

Comment: @Nawaz I show my case there.

Comment: I'm not going to get in to the whole "singletons suck" holy war (beyond just mentioning it), but I *still* wonder why you want a `vector<unique_ptr>` at all if you think the resource should be owned by something else?

Comment: I think I might be on to something.  Please see my edited answer.

Comment: [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) alert. please clarify what you actually want to do, not how you want to do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want a `unique_ptr` that does not own the thing it points to.

Those goals are counter to each other.  The whole point of `unique_ptr` is to own the resource it manages.

It's hard for me to deduce what it is you're *really* after here, as you haven't said *what* you are trying to do -- only *how* you're trying to do it.  Why would you want a `unique_ptr` that doesn't own the resource?

Perhaps what you're really after is a `shared_ptr`, so that multiple instances of a `shared_ptr` can share ownership of the same object.

Yet again, perhaps what you're after is a `weak_ptr`, which itself doesn't (quite) "own" a pointer until it has been promoted to a `shared_ptr`.

After reading your edits, I might have a hunch what you're really after here.  You've said that you want your singleton object to actually own the resource, but you still want your `vector` to have a smart pointer.  Perhaps what you're really after is having the `vector` have a smart pointer which doesn't own the object itself, but will become invalidated or "nulled-out" if the actual owned object is destroyed.

If that's the case, then your singleton should have a `shared_ptr`, and the vector should be a `vector<weak_ptr>`.  When you need to actually get at the object via the `vector`, you'll call `lock` to extract a `shared_ptr` -- check the return from `lock` to ensure that the `weak_ptr` hasn't expired.  You can also just check to see if the `shared_ptr` has expired without locking it by calling `expired`.

Comment: +1, just minor comment. You shouldn't test `expired()` before you `lock()`; it's pointless, since you have to test the result of `lock()` anyway (it could theoretically expire between the call to `expired()` and `lock()`).

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with a plain `unique_ptr<int>` - the name is **unique** pointer, for a reason.

If you really really want to do this (but I am 99.99% sure it's just a symptom of bad design), you could use a custom deleter:

```
template <class T>
struct WeirdDeleter
{
  bool owning;
  explicit WeirdDeleter(bool owning = true) : owning(owning) {}
  void operator() (const T *p) const {
    if (owning) delete p;
  }
};


//Usage:

vector<unique_ptr<int, WeirdDeleter<int>>> v;
unqiue_ptr<int, WeirdDeleter<int>> p(new int(10));
v.push_back(std::move(p));

int *q = new int(20);
v.push_back(unique_ptr<int, WeirdDeleter<int>>(q, WeirdDeleter(false));
```

(I don't know the proposed `make_unique` interface with respect to deleters, so I didn't use it; it would still be usable).

Re-iterating, I think it's a **bad idea**(tm) to do that, but if you really want to, this should be the way.

Comment: Clever, but I think a little too clever.

Comment: @JohnDibling I tried hard to communicate I would steer clear of using this, but I know sometimes circustances (or bosses) require desperate measures.

Comment: No, I understand.  I didn't downvote, in fact I +1'ed.  I guess I'm really just underscoring your asserting that this is a Bad Idea.

Comment: @JohnDibling Yup, that's how I understood it as well.

Answer (score 3):

`unique_ptr` is for the exact use case of it having *exclusive ownership*. So you can't use that for pointing to something and *not* taking the ownership.

The solution is simple: Use `shared_ptr` instead. It doesn't have *exclusive* ownership, instead, all instances of it pointing to the same object will share ownership; and only once the last one goes out of scope, the object will be deleted.

In case you want a pointer which does not interfere with ownership, have a look at `weak_ptr`.

Comment: A `shared_ptr` still owns the resource.  Please edit your answer so that I can better understand what you're getting at here.

Comment: i have. better now? but your answer is still a tad better I guess ;)

Comment: That is better, thanks.  I suspect `shared_ptr` still isn't what OP is after, but +1 regardless.